# Shadow not showing google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Having a problem, I'm trying to add a custom shadow but somehow it is not showing. I checked for bugs using firebug but nothing wrong, the path is also correct. I have no idea why it's not working. code below.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
        map: map,
         position: latlngset, 
         shadow: 'codes/icon/shadow.png',
         icon: baseicon+icon 
        });
```

Comment: Note: Marker shadows were removed in version 3.14 of the Google Maps JavaScript API. Any shadows specified programmatically will be ignored.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With the release of v3.14 as the experimental version, any maps not specifying a version number, will get the new visual refresh behavior, which includes no shadows.

[Changes in the visual refresh](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons)

- All shadows have been removed in the visual refresh. Any shadows specified programmatically will be ignored.

Comment: Wow. Forcing the "clean" visual style by completely disabling shadows is a bit too much. Just for the reference - the parameter for specifying the version is "v", so if you wanted the latest version, just append `&v=3`. If you wanted a particular version number, then it's `&v=3.13`.

Comment: However, only 3 versions are ever available, after the visual refresh change reaches the "frozen" version, there will be no avoiding it.

Comment: just to add, i have discovered that if you include a reference to "shadow" in your code, this may actually cause the main map icon to not display. Removing all references to shadow should fix this.