# How can I show shadow for the markers?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, shadow, markers

I use google map v3 with jquery.gmap.js ( http://labs.mario.ec/jquery-gmap/jquery.gmap.js ). I have a couple of markers with my icon .png and I want to put them a shadow. In default settings in the jquery file we have shadow, but when I use it don't show. I use

```
markers:[
        {
            latitude: 12.681291,
            longitude: 13.361658,
            html: 'some txt',
            popup: true,
            icon: {
                image: "img/my-marker-1.png",
                shadow: "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png",
                iconsize: [20, 34],
                shadowsize: [37, 34],
                iconanchor: [9, 34],
                shadowanchor: [6, 34]
            },
            {
            latitude: 12.589221,
            longitude: 13.251628,
            html: 'some txt 2',
            popup: true,
            icon: {
                image: "img/my-marker-2.png",
                shadow: "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png",
                iconsize: [20, 34],
                shadowsize: [37, 34],
                iconanchor: [9, 34],
                shadowanchor: [6, 34]
            },
            ....
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of google.maps.visualRefresh in your code.

> Shadows are not rendered when `google.maps.visualRefresh` is set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks !!! But I don't have " google.maps.visualRefresh = true; ", so I can change it to false in my code or in jquery.gmap.js code. I put " google.maps.visualRefresh = flase; " after my document ready function, but nothing happen

Comment: This may be the reason 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370309/shadow-not-showing-google-maps-marker

Comment: The jQuery gMap - Google Maps API V3 version is 2.1.2, even that,
so I can't use the markers shadow, is that right ?